# New function added in WCF service is not reflecting on adding the web reference

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5

I am trying to add a web reference to a WCF service. On browsing to that service through the project explorer, the new function added to that service is not getting listed.

This is my code in the *.svc file

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value){;}
    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite){;}
    public double Undo(double value, bool isPound){;}
}
```

Now, while referencing my service as UndoService, my Undo method is not showing up. The following show up by intellisense:

```
(class) CompositeType
(interface) Service1
(interface) Service1Channel
(class) Service1Client
```

This might be a naive question, but I am not able to proceed. I probably am missing something big here. Please help!

Comment: Is `Undo` part of the `IService1` contract?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Thanks for this comment. I had not included Undo in IService1.cs file. Now it is showing up in intellisense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Service1Client` is your proxy class and have to instantiate that class to invoke the service methods.

```
var proxy = new Service1Client();
proxy.Undo(..)
```

Comment: Will try that and update you... Thanks! But what are the other classes for?

Comment: I just tried this. I am prompted for only `GetData()` and `GetDataUsingContract()`

Comment: I had not included it in the contract. Now it is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the reference if you have added new functionality. You can do this by right clicking the existing reference entry and selecting update, this will download the updated service contract.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet What are the Methods shown on the Service1Client (this is the proxy client created when you add the reference)

Comment: I get the two pre-existing methods, among the other methods. But my method of `Undo()` is not turning up.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to either add the method to your contract interface or to decorate the contract method with the `[Operationcontract]` attribute.

EDIT : I kinda misread the question, apply Mark answer before anything.